# How to detect a URL from a given string and return that specific URL only - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a chrome extension. What i want to accomplish is, when i open a received email, the url from the email text should be detected and an alert box should show which url has been returned from the text. What I have done so far is :

```js
function urlify(text) {
    var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
    return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
        return url;
    })
}
var text = document.getElementsByClassName("adn ads")[0].innerText;
var html = urlify(text);
```

This code detects the URL but, also the returns the rest of the text with it. I just want this function to return me that specified detected url.

Comment: Could you perhaps replace `document.getElementsByClassName("adn ads")[0].innerText;` wit an actual example so your snippet could run?

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution I found :

```js
function urlify(text) {
    var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
    return text.match(urlRegex, function(url) {
        return url;
    })
}
var text = document.getElementsByClassName("adn ads")[0].innerText;
var html = urlify(text);
console.log(html[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String#match` to get a matching url. it returns an array so you can shift off the first value to get the matching value.

```js
function urlify(text) {
  return text
    .match(/(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/m)
    .shift()
}
var text = 'some text https://stackoverflow.com some more text'

console.log(
  urlify(text)
)
```